# How can I find all sight-reachable points without iterating over all polygons?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graphics

as the picture shows, the vertices of all polygons are candidate points, stand on the green point and look around, how can i find all sight-reachable points without iterating over all polygons?

[image]

Comment: The established term is *visible*.

Comment: In the general case, it is impossible to find the solution without looking at all polygons.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to enclose each polygon in a bounding circle. A preliminary visibility test first locates all visible circles. Then the regular visibility test needs to consider only the polygons inside the visible circles and can skip the rest.

This approach pays off when the bounding circles are cheaper to test for visibility than the enclosed objects. Unfortunately, I cannot help with the details. I am only familiar with the principle.